# Using a list of lists as a lookup table and updating a value in new list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have an application that creates a list of lists. The second element in the list needs to be assigned using lookup list which also consists of a list of lists.

I have used the "all" method to match the values in the list. If the list value exists in the lookup list, it should update the second position element in the new list. However this is not the case. The == comparative yields a False match for all elements, even though they all exist in both lists.

I have also tried various combinations of index finding commands but they are not able to unpack the values of each list.

My code is below. The goal is to replace the "xxx" values in the newData with the numbers in the lookupList.

```
lookupList= [['Garry','34'],['Simon', '24'] ,['Louise','13'] ]

newData = [['Louise','xxx'],['Garry', 'xxx'] ,['Simon','xxx'] ]  

#Matching values
for i in newData: 
    if (all(i[0] == elem[0] for elem in lookupList)):
        i[1] = elem[1]
```

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was considering this but seeing as my application is producing a list of lists anyway then I thought this might be the best option. Also the strings that are generated can be quite verbose and I am not sure how this would influence a dictionary. I will also be working with several hundred lists in each list. Is a dictionary the most effective way to handle this?

Comment: Absolutely, without a doubt. There won't be any new string objects; the dictionary you'd create from the list references the same string objects anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok thanks, I think my hesitation of using a dictionary stems from my own mental image of a dictionary. If there is no limit to the string length of keys used in a dictionary then this must be the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you want with `all()`, because `elem` is not a local variable outside of the generator expression.

Instead of using a list, use a *dictionary* to store the `lookupList`:

```
lookupDict = dict(lookupList)
```

and looking up matches is a simple constant-time (fast) lookup:

```
for entry in newData:
    if entry[0] in lookupDict:
        entry[1] = lookupDict[entry[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use dictionaries instead, like this:

```
lookupList = newData = {}

old_lookupList = [['Garry','34'],['Simon', '24'] ,['Louise','13'] ]
old_newData = [['Louise','xxx'],['Garry', 'xxx'] ,['Simon','xxx'] ] 

#convert into dictionary
for e in old_newData: newData[e[0]] = e[1]
for e in old_lookupList: lookupList[e[0]] = e[1]

#Matching values
for key in lookupList:
    if key in newData.keys():
        newData[key]=lookupList[key]

#convert into list
output_list = []

for x in newData:
    output_list.append([x, newData[x]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the following code since it can be tweaked and used in different ways:

```
lookupList= [ ['Garry', '34'],['Simon', '24'] ,['Louise', '13'] ]

newData = [ ['Louise', 'xxx'],['Garry', 'xxx'], ['Peter', 'xxx']  ,['Simon', 'xxx'] ]  

#Matching values
for R in newData:
    for i in range(0, len(lookupList) + 1):
        try:
            if lookupList[i][0] == R[0]:
                R[1] = lookupList[i][1]
                break
        except:
            print('Lookup fail on record:', R) 

print(newData)
```